# Get values from luftdaten api specific sensor

Tags: javascript, html, api

Newbie question. I want to get current sensor value from:

```js
var queryURL = "http://api.luftdaten.info/v1/sensor/13481/";
$.getJSON(queryURL, function(data) {
  var result = data.sensordatavalues
  console.log(result);
  var value = result.value
  $('#output').append('The value is ' + value);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="output"></div>
```

I don't get any value. Whats wrong?

Comment: Is anything shown in the logs? From your `console.log` statements?

Comment: The API is returning an Array, not an object

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/xapjou25/

Answer (score 0):

Your api returning an array not an object. And each array has individual array of items again. Below is the sample response from your API. Copy below JSON and put it in JSON formatter tool and see how it looks

Example: https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

[{"sampling_rate":null,"location":{"altitude":"166.8","longitude":"15.7460","latitude":"60.3520","country":"SE","id":6813},"sensor":{"pin":"1","id":13481,"sensor_type":{"manufacturer":"Nova Fitness","name":"SDS011","id":14}},"id":1896266747,"sensordatavalues":[{"value_type":"P1","id":4046181511,"value":"1.67"},{"value_type":"P2","id":4046181512,"value":"0.40"}],"timestamp":"2018-09-11 20:43:54"},{"sampling_rate":null,"location":{"altitude":"166.8","longitude":"15.7460","latitude":"60.3520","country":"SE","id":6813},"sensor":{"pin":"1","id":13481,"sensor_type":{"manufacturer":"Nova Fitness","name":"SDS011","id":14}},"id":1896277409,"sensordatavalues":[{"value_type":"P1","id":4046203944,"value":"1.70"},{"value_type":"P2","id":4046203945,"value":"0.30"}],"timestamp":"2018-09-11 20:46:22"}]